# node.js: connect-mongo and Remember me checkbox

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use connect-mongo to store sessions in a DaaS, then I added a Remember me checkbox in the login page but when I don't check the textbox, it still writes the sessions in the sessions table. I wonder what I can be doing wrong:

server.js:

```
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');
var MongoStore   = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var path = require('path'); //join method
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

//pass passport for configuration
require('./config/passport')(passport); 

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url, {useMongoClient : true}); // connect to our database



// set up our express application
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));    //angular and css files
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

//required for passport
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,  ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60, autoRemove:'native', collection:'AllSessions' }),
    secret: 'foo'
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions

// use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
app.use(flash()); 

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport


//log all other requests here
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    });

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

routes.js (POST code):

```
// process the login form
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
}),

function(req, res, next)
{
    if (!req.body.remember_me)
    {
        return next();
    }
    else{
        app.use(session({
            store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,  ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60, autoRemove:'native', collection:'AllSessions' }),
            secret: 'foo'
        }));
    }
});
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to initialize session when remember me is clicked, so rather than doing that. Initialize the session with a bare-minimum timeout and then use the code below:

```
app.use(session({
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,  ttl: 3600000, autoRemove:'native', collection:'AllSessions' }),
  secret: 'foo'
}));

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
}),

function(req, res, next)
{
        if (!req.body.remember_me)
        {
            req.session.cookie.expires = false;
            return next();
        }
        else{
           req.session.cookie.maxAge = 2628000000; // for one month.
        }
});
```

Comment: doesn't work. I set the ttl of connect mongo to 120 seconds, then tried to run the app. In the login page, I ticked the textbox, logged-in, closed the tab, then reopened the tab after 120 seconds, session did not persist.